# Short poem in Arabic

Tags: arabic, poetry

Is there a classic Arabic poem (irreligious, if it is possible) that resembles the Goethe's ["Uber allen Gipfeln..."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wanderer's_Nightsong#Wanderer.27s_Nightsong_II)? By "resembles" I mean it's length and concise style.

The reason I am looking for such a poem is that poetry is a very useful tool for learning a new language. It is employed in most language manuals and children books. It introduces the new vocabulary, the repetition and vocalization helps to both put the words into the active vocabulary and practice pronunciation. I am looking particularly for a small piece of poetry because it is easier to learn from the beginning to the end, and, hence it is suitable even for a beginner like me. It also stimulates the interest to the culture associated to the given language, thus augmenting the motivation of the learner. You can find more on the topic by googling the phrase "poetry in language teaching".

More broadly, **What popular, concise Arabic poetry exists that is simple enough for a beginner in the language to understand and learn from?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a poem that is irreligious but not classic per say. This poem is good for beginners; they taught us this in grade 2 at the Libyan school. Basic knowledge of the Arabic language is required to read and understand these line

```
انا عصفور صغير .....حيثما شئت اطير
وعلي الغصن اغني .....وعلي الارض اسير
ان يكن راسي صغير ..... فبه عقلا كبير
ان امي علمتني.....علمتني ان اطير
تعلم ايها التلميذ.....فأن العلم نور
```

Enjoy!